# Inline block for arranging image/text - How do I add multiple accordions

Tags: css

Based on another thread I have here: [JQueryUI Accordion: Headers and an inline block for arranging image/text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851162/jqueryui-accordion-headers-and-an-inline-block-for-arranging-image-text)

I have the CSS below, which works fine for one accordion, however when I want to use multiple accordions, which I simply name #accordion2 etc. Is there a quicker way to assign those to this CSS without having to copy/paste it multiple times for each accordion?

I tried:

```
#accordion #accordion2 .foobar {
```

etc. but apparently that's not it.

Apologies for such a simple question!

```
#accordion .foobar { 
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#accordion .foobar .foo {
  display:inline-block;
  width:180px;
  height:125px;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:10px;
}

#accordion .foobar .bar {
  display:inline-block;
  width:290px;         /* enlarge this value, if you want text all on one line */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
#accordion #accordion2 .foobar {
```

with:

```
  #accordion, #accordion2, .foobar {
```

Comment: Thanks, figured I'd be missing something simple in the syntax... :) Will accept as answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Silly errors is what's usually the most iritating. Especially when you try to solve a problem of bigger scale and after whole day of work you realise the issue was caused by a simple typo... :)